# How to find prime numbers within a range in C++ without using flag variables or functions?

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements, primes

In my textbook, the algorithms and flowcharts for this problem use flag variables.So I gave it a try without using flag variables and got a solution (given below).But its implementation in C++ is quite puzzling. We haven't officially learnt goto statements yet.
So my doubt is whether its implementation in C++ is  possible without using functions, goto statements and flag variables and using just loops and conditional statements?

[image: Noob flow chart]

Comment: of course you don't want `goto` in your code, but under the hood loops are using `goto`, hence the requirements are not quite clear

Comment: I see a inner and a outer loop in your picture and no goto, the outer is `do { .... } while(i <=u);`.

Comment: anyhow, did you try anything?

Comment: I'd be wary of "without functions" as a learning goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation of the above idea only using for loops and if statements with an optimization for j:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int l, r;
    bool good; // stores whether a certain i will be prime
    cin >> l >> r;
    for(int i = max(l, 2); i <= r; i ++) // 2 is the first prime number so we can just always start from it if l < 2
    {
        good = true; // we first assume i is prime
        for(int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j ++) // we only need to go to sqrt(i) because every factor of i that is <= sqrt(i) matches another factor that is >= sqrt(i). For example, the number 24 has factors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24, and the 4 factors on the left match the 4 on the right, and all 4 left factors are <= sqrt(24).
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                good = false; // if i is divisible by j, we know it is not prime and can just leave this loop
                break; // leave j loop
            }
        }
        if(good == true)
            cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Another possible optimization is keeping an array of previous primes so you only need to try prime factors, but this would require starting from the first prime number instead of from L.

EDIT: wait sorry I just realized that "good" is a flag variable, but I am not sure if it is possible to solve the problem without it, or by using a goto statement, or especially not a straightforward way to do it.

EDIT (again): found a way to do it without flag variables:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int l, r;
    cin >> l >> r;
    for(int i = max(l, 2); i <= r; i ++) // 2 is the first prime number so we can just always start from it if l < 2
    {
        //good = true; // we first assume i is prime
        for(int j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j ++) // we only need to go to sqrt(i) because every factor of i that is <= sqrt(i) matches another factor that is >= sqrt(i). For example, the number 24 has factors: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24, and the 4 factors on the left match the 4 on the right.
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                i ++; // if i is divisible by j, we can increment i
                j = 1; // and also reset j to 1 (it will be 2 on the next run of the loop
                if(i > r) return 0;
            }
        }
        cout << i << "\n"; // if the code did not reset, it means that i was not divisible by any j and is therefore prime
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah nicely done. Being a coding novice, updation of a loop unofficially and letting the for loop take on the updation half way through never crossed my mind.